# Log errors in visual studio extension

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

What is the right way for logging unexpected exceptions in Visual Studio extensions. Is there any classes in the Visual Studio SDK, or may be exist some libryries from partialy side developers?

Comment: What would you want such a library to do?

Comment: Log errors to the good place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the [ActivityLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.activitylog.aspx) class which logs to the ActivityLog.xml file. That's about it.