# Can't find ActivityLog.xml anywhere after using SVsActivityLog in my extension

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, activitylog

I'm creating a Visual Studio Extension, and would like to see some log output from it for debugging/diagnosing. I have the following code in a MEF IWpfTextViewCreationListener:

```
ActivityLog = ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsActivityLog)) as IVsActivityLog;
ActivityLog.LogEntry((UInt32)__ACTIVITYLOG_ENTRYTYPE.ALE_INFORMATION, this.ToString(), "TestMessage");
```

I ran the extension, breakpoint hit on the LogEntry() call, stepped past it, closed the test instance of Visual Studio, but after that I can only find one ActivityLog.xml in `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio`, and it hasn't been modified since 10 days ago. Where can I find the correct ActivityLog.xml, or what am I missing that's causing it not to be created?

Comment: See this MSDN document which shared how to use the Activity Log:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-the-activity-log, also view the Activitylog class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010247/log-errors-in-visual-studio-extension

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT neither of those resources say anything about where to find or how to create the ActivityLogs.xml file; I had already seen both of those. Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run Visual Studio with the [/log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/log-devenv-exe) switch to create an activity log.

Comment: I wish there were an alternative (like it being on by default) to this method, because I was hoping the ActivityLog would be a means of diagnosing issues on my initial users' machines, but making them do that is not an awesome customer experience. I'll have to find an alternative way to log, like maybe a regular log file in AppSettings somewhere. Good answer, thanks.